# fallback for persistence.xml in spring configuration

Tags: xml, spring, jpa, persistence

My config is as follows:

```
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
            value="classpath:META-INF/spring/environments/${env}/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>
```

What I want is, if

> META-INF/spring/environments/${env}/persistence.xml

is not found, I want LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to load

> META-INF/spring/environments/dev/persistence.xml

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that not out the box. But you could use a small support class to do it.

```
public class ResourceCandidateResolver {

    @Autowired 
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    private String[] candidates;

    public String resolve() {
        for (String candidate : candidates) {
            Resource res = resourceLoader.getResource(candidate);
            if (res.exists())
                return candidate;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String[] getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }

    public void setCandidates(String[] candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }
}
```

And use spel to inject it.

```
<bean id="resourceCandidateResolver" class="beans.ResourceCandidateResolver">
        <property name="candidates">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/persistence-one.xml</value>
                <value>classpath:/persistence-two.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
        value="#{resourceCandidateResolver.resolve()}" />
</bean>
```

Other option is a Configuration class.

Comment: how to use second option (configuration class)?

Comment: @riship89 Just create a Configuration class with a Bean method that creates the LCEMFB searching for a valid persistence configuration inside.